# HTTP post request objective-c

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c

i'm trying to get make a http request to my server and then insert it into mysql table. I do not get any errors.
Objective-c returns Connection Successful.

and no errors in php script, but it does not add the rows to mysql server. i've double checked the table and attribute names. How come its not adding to the mysql?

```
  if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {

                NSString *currentId = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSString *currentName = user.name;


                    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&name=%@&id=%@",currentName,currentId];
                    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

                    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

                    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ratemyplays.com/api/post_user.php"]]];

                    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
                    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
                    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                    if(conn)
                    {
                            NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
                    }


                }
         }];
```

php code.

```
 <?php

 $link = mysqli_connect("mysql12.gigahost.dk","dirts","passwordexample","dirts_api");

 $name = (string)$_POST['name'];
 $id = (int)$_POST['id'];

 mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Users (name, userID) VALUES ('$name', '$id')";


 $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $name = (string)$_GET['name'];
 $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

You said POST? then it should be

```
 $name = (string)$_POST['name'];
 $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: @user3195388 try `var_dump($_REQUEST)`. If yo dont get data it means someting else went wrong.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in /home/www/ratemyplays.com/api/post_user.php on line 11

Comment: @user3195388 what does the dump show you, also remove the first `&` from `&name=%@&id=%@`

Comment: array(4) { ["__atuvc"]=> string(4) "3|45" ["__utma"]=> string(57) "103816195.1740884439.1383749391.1390422126.1390767205.135" ["__utmz"]=> string(94) "103816195.1386151531.116.5.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not provided)" ["__unam"]=> string(32) "7639673-1422883ffc4-1ef17c36-456" }